# How to move items in a row to a specific ordered column when changing to smaller screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap and trying to optimize my web layout for a mobile device. The issue I am having is that I am not sure how to move items from a row into a column in a specific order. I have 2 items in a row. I want it so that the first item moves below the second item in the column. Instead of the second item moving below the first.

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-5 m-auto">
     <div className="">
       <p className="">
          what am I doing. 
       </p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div className="col-md-7 m-auto">
     <p className="">
        what are you doing. 
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) to do this.

For example, if you want the first column to appear second in small screens, then you add `order-sm-2` to that column class.

See the working snippet below - the cols are displayed in the order DIV2 then DIV1 on full screen (click "Expand Snippet" to see this), but DIV1 then DIV2 on medium screens (i.e. in the window below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 m-auto order-md-2">
       DIV1 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7 m-auto  order-md-1" >
      DIV2 
   </div>
 </div>
<div>
```